# Tkinter - Displaying a fullscreen app without a title bar and with an on screen keyboard (Linux)

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, keyboard, fullscreen

I am trying to create a fullscreen tkinter application on a raspberry pi. The application needs to have an on screen keyboard (it's being used on a touchscreen). I would also like there to not be a title bar (I don't want people to be able to close the app, plus it looks cleaner). I've been able to get all of that working except for the title bar using the zoomed attribute, but it can't be combined with any of the other methods I've found to remove the title bar. The keyboard that I am using is florence with a raspbian based raspberry pi 3B+. Below are the cases that I've tried.

Overrideredirect and fullscreen attributes don't allow the onscreen keyboard to work (it opens behind the app).

The splash attribute was very close to working, the issue was my Entry widgets didn't work (when I clicked on them the cursor wouldn't pop up, I could actually tab back to python and the cursor popped up but typed in python. I think this was because the app was behind Python). This was used in combination with the root.geometry to fullscreen the app.

I was able to find two similar stack overflow questions [Updating entry widget using text from onscreen keyboard in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096376/updating-entry-widget-using-text-from-onscreen-keyboard-in-tkinter) and [How do I remove the title bar with tkinter on linux LXDE without overrideredirect or attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278333/how-do-i-remove-the-title-bar-with-tkinter-on-linux-lxde-without-overrideredirec). The first question doesn't require fullscreen (this is where I am at with my current code) and the second doesn't require a keyboard.

```
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-zoomed', True)

    #width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    #height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    #root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
    #root.wm_attributes('fullscreen', True)
    #root.overrideredirect(True)
    #root.attributes('-type', 'splash')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's wrong with `root.attributes("-type", "splash")`? Try using `root.attributes("-topmost", True)` after that. Be careful and always add a way to close the window so you don't have to restart your computer.

Comment: I do actually have a way to close it, it just wasnt included, esc is bound to a function to close it. As for root.attributes("-type", "splash"), it doesn't work with Entry widgets on linux, it doesn't let you type in them. I also just tried root.attributes("-topmost", True), it leaves me with the same screen as root.attributes('-zoomed', True), with a title bar.

Comment: Did you add the `root.attributes("-topmost", True)` after the `root.attributes("-type", "splash")`? To force the window to always be on the top. It works on my Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: That leaves the keyboard behind the tkinter app, similar to the fullscreen attribute. It's like I need a way to tell it to go on top of everything (*except the keyboard*).

Comment: Is the keyboard part of the tkinter app, or is it a separate app that you're running in conjunction with your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround to be able to use the splash attribute: you can bind the click on the entry to `entry.focus_force()` which then allows you to type in the entry. Here is a small example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.attributes("-type", "splash")

root.bind_class("Entry", "<1>", lambda ev: ev.widget.focus_force())

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Note**: I used a class binding to the `tk.Entry`:

```
root.bind_class("Entry", "<1>", lambda ev: ev.widget.focus_force())
```

so that it applies to all the `tk.Entry` in the program. However, if one wants to use a different class of widget, e.g. `ttk.Entry`, the class binding has to be modified to

```
root.bind_class(<class name>, "<1>", lambda ev: ev.widget.focus_force())
```

where `<class name>` will be "TEntry" for `ttk.Entry`, "TCombobox" for `ttk.Combobox` or "Text" for `tk.Text`.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you so much! As a side note, I found out that this does not work with a tkinter.ttk Entry, not a problem for me but important for anyone looking at this later! Thank you!!

Comment: @CameronGreenwalt This is because I did the binding to the `"Entry"` class, for it to work with `ttk.Entry`, you need to do the binding to the `"TEntry"` class. You can also directly bind to a specific widget if you prefer: `entry.bind("<1>", lambda ev: entry.focus_force())`