# (customtkinter) Cannot input text in CTkEntry with -type splash window attributes

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, customtkinter, on-screen-keyboard

This is pretty much the same question except the solution there doesn't work: [Displaying a fullscreen app without a title bar and with an on screen keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391611/tkinter-displaying-a-fullscreen-app-without-a-title-bar-and-with-an-on-screen#comment119119008_67391611)

I am trying to create a fullscreen application on a raspberry pi, since Raspbian Bookworm doesn't have matchbox support I am forced to use wvkbd as my onscreen keyboard (my project involves a touchscreen) Sadly tkinter does not show the onscreen keyboard above the fullscreen GUI (using Fullscreen=True as an window attribute or overrideredirect)

```
 mainwindow.geometry('800x480')
 mainwindow.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
```

These window attributes created a fullscreen windowed window and now the keyboard called by os.system actually shows up above the tkinter window but when I try to enter something in a CTkEntry box the entry box doesn't show a cursor and all the keyboard input goes into the terminal I opened my python program from

```
searchframe = ctk.CTkFrame(master=mainwindow, width=800, height=480, fg_color='black')
        searchframe.place(x=0,y=0)
    
        searchentry = ctk.CTkEntry(searchframe, width=670, height=70, font=ctk.CTkFont(family='Ubuntu', size=30))
        searchentry.place(x=30,y=25)

    
        searchentry.bind("<Button-1>", searchMenu.keyboard)

 def keyboard(event):
        os.system('wvkbd-mobintl -L 200 -fg 000000 -fg-sp 000000 --text ffffff --text-sp ffffffs --landscape-layers simple')
```

I tried the solution in the link above but none of it worked, I made sure I changed the class name to customtkinter ones and also have tried binding it to my specific entry widget.

Comment: Please read the steps of how to ask a question and provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible.